# How to force bootstrap dropdown over iframe in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a simple test I am running on Bootstrap and discovered an issue that only occurs in IE10.

If you have a dropdown and a iframe below it, the dropdown when clicked aligns below the iframe.  I have an example [here](http://papershare.ravennainteractive.com/test/)

I have tried z-index a million different ways. I have tested in all browsers and only IE10 appears to have the issue.

while I know IE10 isn't on ever Windows machine yet, its coming and I don't want menus failing... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As referenced [here](http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix).  It might be worth a shot.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
    });
});
```

Also, I think you would need to add style="position:relative;" to the iframe to achieve z-index.

Comment: I'll double check the position.  But the ?wmode is being added by the media plugin

Comment: checked and that appears to not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. It worked for me. Check in your situation.

[Bootstrap 3 navbar on pages containing iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866189/bootstrap-3-navbar-on-pages-containing-iframes)

It suggests to use "the complete closing statement."

```
<iframe frameBorder="0", width="100%", height="500", id=generic src="generic_order.html"></iframe>
```